# MySql 3306 port being taken, I want it back

Tags: mysql

I install XAMPP first, then I might install some other program, I don't know which one, suddenly I can't start MySQL through XAMPP, then I uninstall XAMPP, use MAMP instead, I set the Apache port to 80, MySQL port to 3307, it works, but if I change MySQL port to 3306, it doesn't work.

So I think there might be some program take the 3306 port and keep running.

I want to find that program take 3306 port, uninstall it, or please tell me how to unbind the 3306 port and then assign the default 3306 port to MAMP.

I am using MAC.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried rebooting?

Answer (score 1):

1. Discover what process is using it `lsof -n -i4TCP:3306 | grep LISTEN`
2. Kill, close or uninstall